# How can I reformat JSON / Dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have the below list -

```
[{'metric': 'sales', 'value': '100', 'units': 'dollars'}, 
{'metric': 'instock', 'value': '95.2', 'units': 'percent'}]
```

I would like to reformat it like the below in Python -

```
{'sales': '100', 'instock': '95.2'}
```

I did the below -

```
a = [above list]
for i in a:
    print({i['metric']: i['value']})
```

But it outputs like this -

```
{'sales': '100'}
{'instock': '95.2'}
```

I would like these 2 lines to be a part of the same dictionary

Comment: I edited the post and added details on what I tried. Guess I was too late

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is a knowledge base for *specific* programming problems -- not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
Posting with no attempt is a very reliable way to get down-votes -- as you've noticed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
d = [{'metric': 'sales', 'value': '100', 'units': 'dollars'}, 
{'metric': 'instock', 'value': '95.2', 'units': 'percent'}]

new_d = {e["metric"]: e["value"] for e in d}
# output: {'sales': '100', 'instock': '95.2'}
```

I believe that it's best to try it first by yourself, and then post a question in case you don't succeed. You should consider posting your attempts next time.

Comment: Thanks @AdamGold. I edited the post and added details on what I tried.
Guess I was too late